# Good Slideshow DVD programs?

Tags: dvd, photos, burning, slideshow

I want to burn a bunch of pictures to a DVD slideshow.  However, Google reveals that there are tons of software programs that claim to do this.  Can anyone recommend one of them without me having to download 20 of them only to discover half don't work and the other half are free trials to $29 software that doesn't work either?

The only one which I have tried out so far is DVD Slideshow GUI, which is simply a mess of programs.  It was free, but it crashed a whole bunch, spit errors at me when i tried to preview and never worked when I tried to export the slideshow to mpg.

Comment: For which OS would this be for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i can only recommend [**MemoriesOnTV**](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Authoring-tools/Digital-Album/MemoriesOnTV.shtml), although it costs slighty more than $29

creates the most visually elegant slideshow on TV and very easy to use.

cheaper would be [Windows Moviemaker](http://devrexster.googlepages.com/mmk) & [DVDFlick](http://www.dvdflick.net/), but i doubt you'll get the effects and the quality.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help guys.  However, I finally went with None of the Above...I borrowed a Mac and used iMovie and iDVD.  That said, if I had not had access to a mac, I probably would have gone the Windows Movie Maker and DVDFlick route, so you get my checkmark. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Did you download the latest version from here?
[DVD slideshow GUI](http://download.videohelp.com/tin2tin/) and did you allow the installer to download and install checked programs Avisynth, Ffdshow, Xvid, Ingburn... etc. If you didn't this is the reason it won't work... You should only uncheck those programs if you allready have them installed.

Comment: Yes, I allowed everything to install

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac, I create photo slideshows in iPhoto, export theses to a movie files, and then burn with iDVD. iDVD's built in photo slideshows are far less aesthetically appealing that iPhoto exported slideshows.