# Program for making blu-ray slideshow movies of photos (simple, cheap or free)?

Tags: photos, blu-ray, slideshow

Can you recommend a program for making *blu-ray* slideshow movies of photos (free or cheap)? for burning photo slideshow movies to blu-ray for watching on any standard settop consumer blu-ray player.

This is for a relative who would not wish to have to go through many steps to achieve the results. My research has found tools that look easy to use but only DVD based (we're in the HD 1080p era).

**My Research so far:**

(just so you know what I've already considered but not the answer.)

**MemoriesOnTV** - no HD blu-ray support

I'm looking for something like MemoriesOnTV, but a "MemoriesOnTV HD version" - would be what I'm looking for for blu-ray.

Memories on TV does not provide a feature for burning to Blu-ray
http://www.codejam.com/slideshow/index.htm

With HD TVs becoming commonplace, they need to catch up.

**Photo DVD** - looks good as well, but not blu-ray

http://www.vso-software.fr/products/photodvd/photodvd.php

**Wedding Slideshow Studio** - does Blu-ray cheesy Wedding theme interface, would prefer general purpose tool which this tool might be capable of.

http://www.wedding-slideshow-studio.com/how-to-burn-photo-to-blu-ray-disc.php

**Searches on superuser...**

Only found DVD-based answers

[How to make a DVD movie of my photos?](https://superuser.com/questions/60231/how-to-make-a-dvd-movie-of-my-photos)

[Good Slideshow DVD programs?](https://superuser.com/questions/39324/good-slideshow-dvd-programs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe Premiere Elements will do the job.

Here are the instructions:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/PremiereElements/7.0/WS645B5E9D-30B2-4340-A06B-2B50117AE891.html

I have to say, these instructions by Adobe themselves could be better.

(I don't work for Adobe, by the way).

Answer (score 0):

Premier is not in my opinion ideal it is very much video orientated. Proshow Gold or Producer is the industry standard for slideshow production on Windows (Fotomagicao for MAC)  cost for Gold version is about £70.00 and well worth it. Full support for DVD/Bluray/HD trial version is available from Photodex